# How to upload files to the sites/default/files place without going to the Cpanel backend just through admin backend?

Tags: importing-exporting

How to upload files to the *sites/default/files* folder without going to the Cpanel backend, just through the admin backend?

I need to put there a set of Ubercart images to make a *bulk product import* via ***feeds*** and ***.csv*** sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload files from UI you can use the [elFinder file manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/elfinder) module. I've checked this module. Seems it's what you're looking for.
You can upload multiple files from admin UI itself. You can access the URL like follows

```
http://example.com/elfinder
```

**Features**

> - Integrated with WYSIWYG API  capable editors: CKEditor, FCKeditor, TinyMCE, BUEditor (D6), jWYSIWYG (D6), YUI, WYMeditor
> - Multiple file upload
> - File copying/moving with Drag & Drop support
> - Quick file and directory rename
> - Image resizing
> - Lightbox-preview
> - Contect menu with generic file/directory operations
> - Inline text file editing
> - Favories directory list
> - Directory selection history
> - Working with archives
> - File descriptions

screenshot

[image]